# Showing mutual contiguity

Tags: probability-theory, statistical-inference, weak-convergence

The problem:

> Let $P_n$ and $Q_n$ be the distribution of the mean of a sample of size $n$ from the $N(0, 1)$ and the $N(\theta_n, 1)$ distribution, respectively. Show that $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are mutually contiguous if and only if $\theta_n=O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

My attempt goes like this. In my book, it says that if $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are such that $dP_n/dQ_n$ converge in distribution to $\exp{N(\mu, \sigma^2)}$, they are mutually contiguous if and only if $\mu=-\sigma^2/2$.

$dP_n/dQ_n$ is the likelihood ratio, so
$$
\frac{dP_n}{dQ_n}=\frac{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\right\}}{\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\theta_i)^2\right\}}=\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\theta_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\theta_i\right)\right\}
$$

Assume that $\theta_n=O(1/\sqrt{n})$, meaning that $\theta_n=\mu_n/\sqrt{n}$ where $\mu_n=O(1)$. Define $Y_n=-2X_n\mu_n$. Then (under $Q_n$)
$$
X_n \sim N\left(\frac{\mu_n}{\sqrt{n}}, 1\right) \Longrightarrow Y_n =-2X_n\mu_n \sim N\left(\frac{-2\mu_n^2}{\sqrt{n}}, 4\mu_n^2\right) \Longrightarrow Y_n/\sqrt{n}\sim N\left(\frac{-2\mu_n^2}{n}, \frac{4\mu_n^2}{n}\right)
$$
and the sum can be written as $\sum_i -2X_i\theta_i=\sum_i -2X_i\frac{\mu_i}{\sqrt{i}}=\sum_i Y_i/\sqrt{i}$.

Now, what I wanted is actually there - the mean of $Y_n/\sqrt{n}$ is minus one half of the variance. But some questions remain on how to complete this:

1. What can I say about the limit of this? Not sure how to approach it. I would guess that I should use the $O(1\sqrt{n})$ in some way to make sure that that assumption is necessary.
2. What does $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ mean for the first sum, where we have a quadratic term? Should I simply use proportionality since it's a constant?

Any hints are much appreciated!

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry, I don't think I'm following. I think I (implicitly) used that, as I used a variance of $1$ for $X_n$ (i.e. one element of the sum in the mean), so the mean will have a variance of $1/n$. But even so, why does that require $\theta_n$ to be $O(1/\sqrt{n})$? Thanks for the help. Maybe it is obvious from what you wrote, but I am unable to see it.

Comment: @DilipSarwate If you don't mind me spamming a little, I think I might get it now. Looking at this reference: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Books/Asymptopia/old-Contiguity.pdf on page 5, Example <12>, that is what I have but with $\delta=\theta$ and $\alpha=0$ (and reversed). Is it simply that I shouldn't have a sum when looking at $dP_n/dQ_n$, but only $x$ like in that link? And with $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ we have a finite limit of $\theta_n^2$?

Comment: Deleting previous comment. The _sample means_ $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are normal random variables exactly (not asymptotically or in the limit) with means $0$ and $S_n=\frac {T_n}{n} =\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i$ respectively and common variance $\frac 1n$. Noting that
$T_n = nS_n$, we can write the likelihood ratio $\frac{dP_n}{dQ_n}$ as
$$\frac{dP_n}{dQ_n} = \frac{\exp(-nx^2/2)}{\exp(-n(x-S_n)^2/2)}
= \exp(-nxS_n + nS_n^2/2) 
= \exp\left(-xT_n \, + \frac{T_n^2}{2n}\right)$$ This is essentially what Example 12 in your link has, and contiguity requires that $T_n^2$ converge to a finite constant.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks, I think it's all falling into place now. One last question, if you don't mind. What I don't fully understand is what $x$ is here and why we have a sum of means (i.e. your $T_n$), but not of the variables (i.e. $\sum x_i$). Is it somehow implied by the notation (which is new to me) that we are considering *one* likelihood ratio, and not the product? That is, assume we have a set of variables $x_1, ..., x_n$ and we consider the likelihood ratio for each $x_i$? I think that is my confusion, because with a sum the exponent would increase with increasing $n$...

Comment: And if you would add your comment as an answer as well I'd gladly accept it.